# What causes the computer clock to change radically and how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, boot, macbook

My girlfriend just sent me the following photo:

[image: Over nine thousaaaaand]

Apparently that was what greeted her, along with a load of license expiry warnings, when she booted her laptop this morning. She then rebooted to be told it was now 2001. I believe it then died, and it now won't boot. It's a 2009-ish white Macbook running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

I'm at work so I'm looking for any ideas as to what has gone horribly wrong before I try to troubleshoot it tonight. All help is greatly appreciated!

Update: Apparently it boots into OS X fine, but still has a system clock of 2001. I'm guessing the motherboard battery died, though I won't know until later.

Comment: that is beautiful, I have never seen it go into the future when the battery dies, usually it goes back to Dec 31st 1969

Comment: Yep, definitely looks like a dead or dying CMOS battery. Get it replaced.

Comment: Looks like they're ~£15, so this is a job for the Apple store as the laptop is still (just) inside its warranty. Will update with an answer once it's fixed!

Comment: Crap, you have a time machine, don't fix it!

Comment: Something's strange -- though the symptoms do point to the CMOS battery, the CMOS battery should last 5 years or longer.

Answer (score 7):

The [CMOS battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery) on the motherboard is (nearly) depleted and must be replaced.